# pip installation failing SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on windows

Tags: python, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate

I am using a company computer on Windows. I have my own index that is hosted on an https website. I am aware that i can avoid using https using `trusted-host`. But i wanted to use it.

I am trying to install packages as follows:

```
 pip install -i https://pathtoindex/simple/ pkgname
```

But i get the following error:

```
Could not fetch URL [...] There was a problem confirming the ssl
certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
```

I also did try to download the .pem certification file for my domain from Mozilla, I tried the following command:

```
pip --cert dirtocert/cert.pem install -i https://pathtoindex/simple/ pkgname
```

This doesn't work either though, still get the same error.

Comment: What's the .pem file you're refering to? You downloaded the correspoding CA file for your certificate?

Comment: This is where I am a bit fuzzy, all I did was go on Mozilla and download it from the https website on which the pip index is hosted.

Comment: Can you post the url of the index you're referring to? Is it a private one? Do you use a self signed certificate for it?

Comment: I created a custom index. It is hosted on the intranet. The certificate was provided by the IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the root CA certificate for the certificate IT provided for your service. Either it's a self-signed one or it's one provided by a commercial provider. In both cases your IT department should be able to provide the certificate.

You also could use openssl to have a look at your certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect your-domain.com:443
```

*(* Alternatively you can use your browser for this. Click on the lock in the address bar and select 'details' (or something similar)..)*

Under "Server certificate" there should be an "issuer"-section. If the issuer is your company, you're most likely using a self-signed certificate. If it's something else (e.g. COMODO, StartCom, etc.) you can use their root or intermediate CA certs.

Comment: I did verify and the issuer is my company. However, i am still not able to get it to work, the process you are describing seems to be very similar to what i did above. Is there a possibility that proxies are playing a role here? Thanks.

Comment: But the proxy should not be an issue since the website hosting the pip index is within the intranet, correct?

Comment: You can use openssl to test your connection `openssl s_client -connect your-domain.tld:443`. And `openssl s_client -connect -CAfile cacert.pem your-domain.tld:443` to provide a CAcertificate to check against. [Here's](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) a link to the full documentation.

Comment: I tried both commands, i believe on your second command the -connect should occur right before your-domain. Anyway, for both i get the following: `verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain`. Also something i noticed is that the output shows a server certificate, I noticed that that certificate is exactly what i was using in the .pem file.

Comment: Never mind, i got it to work, i found the certificate that my browser was using. The issue is that i was using the certificate from my website.